# Confusion regarding Capacitance of Vaccum

Tags: capacitance, vacuum

Capacitance is given by:-

C = $\frac{Q}{V}$

$Q$ represents change in charge.

$V$ represents change in potential difference.

If the dielectric material of a capacitor is vacuum, charges will be able to move through vacuum and thus, no charge will develop on plates.

Does this mean that even if the dielectric constant of vacuum is non- zero, is its capacitance zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If the dielectric material of a capacitor is vacuum, charges will be
> able to move through vacuum and thus, no charge will develop on
> plates.

Charges will not be able to move through a vacuum or an insulator (dielectric) between the capacitor plates unless the capacitor is subjected to very high voltages far above its rating causing a dielectric breakdown, or in the case of an insulator, in the form of very small leakage currents.
The breakdown field strength for a vacuum variable capacitor is in the range of 20-40 x 10$^6$V/m. It is even higher for some dielectrics (e.g., 60-170 x 10$^6$V/m for teflon)$^1$.

> Does this mean that even if the dielectric constant of vacuum is non-
> zero, is its capacitance zero?

The value of the dielectric constant, a.k.a. relative electric permittivity is always greater than or equal to one. It is one for a vacuum or free space.

In terms of its physical characteristics, the capacitance of a parallel plate capacitor having a vacuum between its plates is given by

$$C=\frac{\epsilon_{r}\epsilon_{o} A}{d}$$

where $A$ and $d$ is the plate area and separation, respectively, in meters, and $\epsilon_{r} =$ is the dielectric constant or relative permittivity, and $\epsilon_{o}=$ electrical permittivity of a vacuum or free space = 8.85 x 10$^{-12} F/m$

Hope this helps.

$^1$ Source: Wikipedia art Vacuum variable capacitor.